# IP address, network ID, host ID and subnet ID

Tags: network, subnet

I am studying a course about computer networking and again I stumbled upon a section that raised a question. I found very helpful people in this forum and I hope you can help me once again.
During the lesson I was given the IP address example: 10.0.1.10 and I was told that the first couple octets are for the network ID, the third is for the subnet ID and the fourth for the Host ID.

But I'm confused. This is a Class A IP address so the network ID should only be the first octet. Why is it including also the second one? Am I missing something?
Thank you!

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years _before_ the commercial Internet!) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). We have not used network classes in this century.

Comment: See [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for how to do subnetting, including the very last section that discusses network classes from a historical perspective.

Comment: I understand. But I am a beginner and this is part of my program. I'm just trying to make sense and to do so I have to start from the roots. :( Can you answer my question?

Comment: The link I provided explains it.

Comment: Actually, you need to learn the proper way to subnet, first, then you can learn about history of things like network classes, which have nothing to do with networking today. Trying to do it the other way around leads to the confusion you have.

Comment: thank you for the link! I will study it right away :)